# Firebase - Alerta de tras subir datos al recuperar conexión

Tags: android, firebase

Llevo ya casi una semana buscando como hacer esto, el tema es que tengo un app en `android` (`java`) con un formulario (con fotografía incluida) y por temas de la ubicación donde se usa el `app` no se pueden enviar los datos inmediatamente, por lo que no es hasta retomar la conexión(`wifi, 4G/3G`), que empieza la carga de datos(todo esto con el funcionamiento nativo de `firebase`), para facilitar el uso he tenido que quitar el `progressDialog` que indicaba el porcentaje de carga y hacer que solo se limpie el formulario para que los usuarios pueda hacer más registros.
Tengo dos consultas al respecto:

- 1. Como hago para que se carguen todas las fotografías? Ya que se envían los registros, pero solo la imagen del último registro.
- 2. Como puedo alertar al usuario que ha iniciado el proceso de carga y que ha concluido exitosamente? Desde luego esto está sucediendo por detrás con las funciones nativas de `firebase`, pero el usuario no llega a enterarse si pasó o no.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Para continuar las cargas de las imagenes, vas a necesitar hacer uso del `sessionUri`, podes leer un poco mas sobre esto en el siguiente link directo

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#continuing_uploads_across_process_restarts

Cuando inicias una subida de imagen ya sea que te encuentras online o no, se genera un hilo aparte con los datos que se van a mandar a Firebase, estos datos tienen un callback que van a actualizar tu UI una vez estos terminen.

Ademas, tanto firebase database como firestore database almacenan por ellos mismos los datos de la sesion si no esta en linea para enviarlos a Firebase, pero Storage no, es por eso que vas a necesitar guardar ese `sessionUri` en persistencia por si algo sucede, para que luego puedas continuar

Como el sessionUri lo guardas en `onProgress()` , deberias esperar que el callback cuando se suben tus datos sea llamado en el `onSuccessListener()` , si llamas a `onCompleteListener()` este va a devolver tanto para un fallo o un acierto en la subida

```
//Escucha los cambios de estado, los errores y la finalización de la carga.
uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
        System.out.println("Subiendo.. " + progress + "% terminado");
    }
}).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        System.out.println("Upload is paused");
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Manejo de errores
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // Manejamos las subidas exitosas aqui
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Gastón muchas gracias por el apoyo y darte el tiempo de detallarlo, lo intentaré y te comento como me fue!